# Turning question with answers into community wiki?

Tags: support, status-completed, community-wiki

I can't find the way to turn a question of mine into a wiki (the help says to check the check-box under the main frame when editing. As I'm not going blind any time soon (I hope) I can surely say there is no check-box in the edit mode).

I cannot find the answer in the main Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The community wiki option has been removed from questions. You can read more about the reasons here: [Community Wiki checkbox missing in action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action).

Individual answers can be marked as community wiki. If you feel a question *needs* to be community wiki, you can flag it for moderator attention to have it converted.

Answer (score 2):

Jonatr I personally don't feel CW necessary for this [particular question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/what-software-do-you-use-as-complementary-to-your-gis-desktop-server). It expresses a complete thought in and of itself and is not likely to benefit from multiple authors. Now if someone wanted to roll up all of the "best of" answers into a single post *that single answer* could and should be community wiki.

Comment: OK, I agree with you. Thanks. Maybe making it into a "best of" post would be useful, but in that case I'd divide it into two parts, as software for analysis is completely different than software for programming.

Answer (score 1):

While there are some wiki-like aspects of gis.se, it isn't really a wiki.

Maybe we should encourage users to push stuff over to wikipedia?

I'm reluctant to suggest http://wiki.gis.com/ since I've seen so few people reference it.

Comment: I confess I haven't spent time on wiki.gis.com. I just poked around a bit and it does seem to be a pretty good site. I will look there more often now. I don't know how "big" an answer should be before it is better presented on another site. I don't think we're ready for that yet.